# Zabbix "Trigger overview" empty after upgrade to v5.0.3

Tags: zabbix

Issue:

At **Monitoring -> Trigger Overview** view (URL http://<zabbix_server>/zabbix/overview.php) which used (in last versions such as 4.4) to show a overview of all problem and recovered triggers, now it's empty while in **Monitoring -> Problems** view (URL http://<zabbix_server>/zabbix/zabbix.php?action=problem.view) it shows the problems accordingly.

Additional info:

- No filters selected
- Selected to "show -> problems" in the filter
- Zabbix version 5.0.3

Comment: it's working in my 5.0.3 installations, so maybe you do have a filter? also use CTRL+F5 to refresh frontend after the upgrade

Comment: Yes, already refreshed the frontend. See, when filter MPPR selected in Problems view, there are 5 triggers -> https://i.imgur.com/h4AFs9H.png. When same filter selected in Overview, just 4 triggers -> https://i.imgur.com/OKockb1.png. When no filter selected in Overview, just 1 trigger -> https://i.imgur.com/t3GNzQi.png

Comment: Hm... ok. No idea.